# CakePHP 3.7.* migrations: skip or change schema.lock file generation path

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-3.7

From documentation:

> In order for the diff feature to work, a .lock file is generated everytime you migrate, rollback or bake a snapshot, to keep track of the state of your database schema at any given point in time. You can skip this file generation, for instance when deploying on your production environment, by using the --no-lock option for the aforementioned command:

```
$ bin/cake migrations migrate --no-lock

$ bin/cake migrations rollback --no-lock

$ bin/cake bake migration_snapshot MyMigration --no-lock
```

We use lastest CakePHP 3.7.* and platform.sh for our app deploying.

@ platform config file we have this lines:

```
deploy: |
    set -e
    bin/cake migrations migrate --no-lock
...
```

and error log:

```
PHP Warning:  fwrite(): supplied resource is not a valid stream resource in /app/vendor/cakephp/cakephp/src/Console/ConsoleOutput.php on line 253

[2019-02-12 06:21:49.622155] Launching command 'set -e
bin/cake migrations migrate --no-lock
...
Warning Error: mkdir(): Read-only file system in [/app/vendor/cakephp/migrations/src/ConfigurationTrait.php, line 74]
```

It´s there way to generate *.lock files in writable tmp dir?

Answer (score 1):

It's not trying to create `.lock` files because you've told it to skip that part in your command.

Instead, it's trying to create the [seeds directory](https://github.com/cakephp/migrations/blob/master/src/ConfigurationTrait.php#L74) because it was not able to find it. If the docs are correct, adding a `config/Seeds` directory ought to allow it to continue past that step and either succeed or illuminate another problem.

Comment: Thanks for right direction, we add in platform.yaml ```'/config/Seeds': 'shared:files/config/Seeds'```and now migrations migrate runing without warnings